# ERROR: 181 timed out after 0.012s (1282 1283) mMajorChangePending=0

Tags: objective-c, swift, timeout, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

There are a few threads on SO regarding this issue but none is answered really.

Apparently it has something to do with AVAudioPlayer but that's about it. No one seems to be able to point out what exactly to fix.

In my case, I get that error message but everything works fine. The audio file gets played, no crash, nothing. Anyhow I'd still like to know why I'm getting that error message and eventually, eliminate it completely.

This error doesn't show up often at all. It almost never happens but maybe once every 40 tries I'd get one... it is so random so I'm not sure what to do about it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is your code a mix of Swift and Objective-C?

Comment: I did read that this almost only happens to Swift but no, pure Objective-C here.

Comment: If you would post the code where it is loading and playing, it would be helpful. As a shot in the dark, it may be that the sound file has not completed loading. I noticed in my code that if I called prepare immediately before play, I would get that error.